# How to get Matlab code into a LaTeX document?

Tags: sourcecode, matlab

I'm trying to put in my thesis matlab code but the results are not very good. I would get something like that but I don't know what packages using and how to create this result:

[image]

Comment: Please reformulate the title of your question. I think the `listings` package is what you're looking for.

Comment: There's also [`mcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package), which uses `listings`.

Comment: There's also [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) and `minted`, which use the Python syntax highlighting library Pygments.  These can highlight Matlab code and Matlab interactive sessions.

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, please make sure that the resulting code listing is copy-and-pasteable. Your 25 readers will hate it otherwise.

Comment: The [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package is your friend, here; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer the [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package. It's a little trouble to set up by the output is very neat and tidy -- and it has syntax highlighting.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,bgcolor=bg]{matlab}


% Gradient descent algo for linear regression
% author: Nauman (recluze) 

%set the data
X=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1; 22 49 80 26 40 54 91];
Y=[20 24 42 22 23 26 55];
hold on;
plot(X(2,:),Y, 'x');

% set the actual values of W
W = [5.775 0.474]';
YAct = (W' * X);

% GRADIENT DESCENT
W = zeros(2,1);     % initialize W to all zeros
m = size(X,2);      % number of instances
n = size(W,1);      % number of parameters
alpha = 0.000025;    % gradient descent step size

disp('Starting Weights:');

\end{minted}   
\end{document}
```

You'll have to call `pdflatex` with `--shell-escape` though and you will have to install a package that provides `pygmentize` command.