# Need to show MATLAB code in TeX document, using pdfLaTeX

Tags: graphics, comments, matlab

I am trying to make a simple document, showing MATLAB code, and some images. This is my template that I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{}

\begin{document}

I want to put MATLAB code here.

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6in]{case2Rect.png}
\caption{Blah}
\label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that MATLAB code is full of comments that use '%', and so when I try to compile using pdfLaTeX, it crashes. I am using TexMaker btw. Anyway, I was wondering what technique might be used to go around this problem. I simply need to show MATLAB code, along with some images. I am relatively new to LaTeX.

Thanks.

Comment: There have been a few similar questions, see if any of these help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/inserting-matlab-code-in-the-appendix , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84777/how-to-get-matlab-code-into-a-latex-document http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69382/inline-matlab-code

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I now get this error "! LaTeX Error: File `mcode.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop." when I just simply try to add the mcode package. I thought I had this setup to update packages automatically...

Comment: `mcode` isn't part of either MikTeX or TeX Live, so either use plain `listings` or download and install `mcode`: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok... I guess my question then is how do I set up TexMaker to automatically download packages... :-/ I honestly do not know how to install packages. I tried once and it was a complete and utter nightmare.

Comment: How about substitute every `%` in your code with `\%`?

Comment: Texmaker doesn't really have anything to do with package installing. If you use MikTeX then you can have MikTeX install missing packages automatically, *but not `mcode`*. `mcode` is not on CTAN, and not in the databases of MikTeX, so it wouldn't work for that anyway. A one-time solution is to just place `mcode.sty` in the same folder as your `.tex` document.

Comment: Or not use `mcode` at all, just plain `listings` as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75124/586

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Listings package to include all kinds of code into Latex. The listings package supports syntax highlighting of a number of languages. You can also define own styles.

[A good place to start](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings)

Comment: I think what you wrote in your answer has been extensively said in the above comments...